# Different Collation for Server and Database, which is "Stronger"?

Tags: sql-server-2008, collation

I have a sqlserver 2008 running with collation set to: Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS

I also have a table on that server with collation set to: SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_CS_AS

In the table I have a column named Material which contains

abcf
abcf
DF

```
SELECT Allowable  FROM [Mat].[dbo].[D100601EN6115K3] WHERE Thickness = 2 AND CHARINDEX('F', Material)>0
```

It returns the allowable values for all three rows containing an "f" or "F"
How can I make my search case sensitive so that I only get the allowable from the last row?
I hope there is an easy way because I don't want to set up the whole server again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the COLLATE clause to change the collation of the expression

```
SELECT Allowable
FROM [Mat].[dbo].[D100601EN6115K3]
WHERE Thickness = 2 AND CHARINDEX('F', Material COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_CS_AS) > 0
```

The COLLATE clause can go against a whole expression or just a column reference.

If Material already has the collation Material COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_CS_AS then it should be

```
CHARINDEX('F' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP437_CS_AS, Material)
```

Sorry, it isn't 100% clear which column is CS: Material or another one.

Basically, `'F'` is the collation of the server or database if different